# How to access Symfony image filter settings from twig

Tags: symfony, macros, twig

I would like to build a macro, which automatically reads the image's width and height of the corresponding filter.

Let's say, this is a part of my **images.yml**

```
liip_imagine:
  filter_sets:
    original:
      path: original
      quality: 80
    small:
      path: small
      quality: 75
      filters:
        thumbnail: { size: [400, 400], mode: inset }
```

How can I re-use the size in my **Twig macro**?

```
{% macro img(media, filter) %}
{% spaceless %}
    <img
        src="{{ media.filename|imagine_filter(filter) }}"
        alt=""

        {# is there something like this? #}
        width="{{ imagine_get_filter(filter).filters[0].size[0] }}"
        height="{{ imagine_get_filter(filter).filters[0].size[1] }}"
    />
{% endspaceless %}
{% endmacro %}
```